# tsung cluster error:too few file descriptors available

Tags: file-descriptor, tsung

I'am using tsung's cluster.
I have modified the limits of file descriptors.
The node which I take it as the slave will report errors:

> ts_launcher:(2:<0.49.0>) WARNING !!! too few file descriptors
>   available (1024), you should decrease maxusers (currently 60000)

Can anyone give some help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

1. First, check the current system limit for file descriptors:

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
   ```
2. If the setting is lower than 64000, edit the /etc/sysctl.conf file, and   reset the fs.file-max parameter:

   ```
   fs.file-max = 64000
   ```
3. Then increase the maximum number of open files on the system by editing the /etc/security/limits.conf configuration file. Add the following entry:

   ```
   *        -        nofile        8192
   ```
4. Edit the /etc/pam.d/system-auth, and add this entry:

   ```
   session required /lib/security/$ISA/pam_limits.so
   ```
5. Reboot the machine to apply the changes.

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS/RHEL, change the file descriptor limit in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf
* soft nofile 64000
* hard nofile 64000
```

Reboot the machine:

```
sudo reboot
```

Check the limit again:

```
ulimit -n
64000
```